# Python 3: No module named 'AudioSignal'

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

The code below gives this error when I'm trying to execute it:

```
>>> import nussl
>>> history = nussl.AudioSignal('HistoryRepeatingPropellerHeads.wav')
```

Error is:

```
C:\Users\MyPCUser>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nussl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MyPCUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nussl\__init__.py", line 26, in <modul
e>
    from .core.constants import *
  File "C:\Users\MyPCUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nussl\core\__init__.py", line 7, in <m
odule>
    from audio_signal import AudioSignal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audio_signal'
>>>
```

Comment: what was the error? Also please fix formatting

Comment: Describe the filetree please

Comment: I'm trying to use the code as described here:
https://github.com/interactiveaudiolab/nussl/blob/master/nussl/separation/ft2d.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module does not work yet (23-Feb-2019) with Python 3 according to [Issue 135](https://github.com/interactiveaudiolab/nussl/issues/135) and [Issue 133](https://github.com/interactiveaudiolab/nussl/issues/133). From the [docs](https://github.com/interactiveaudiolab/nussl/tree/development): *This package has been tested with python 2.7, but not python 3.x yet. Use python 3 at your own peril!*

I got the same issue when trying to use it with Python 3.